# Xcode UISlider is added to another cell after scrolling

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, ios8

when I scroll in my TableView the UISlider in row 2 is moved weirdly to another cell.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NewsTickerFilterCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

...

```
else if (indexPath.row == 2) {

        UISlider *radiusSlider = (UISlider *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:20];
        if (!radiusSlider) {

            // ... noch nicht erstellt
            radiusSlider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(screenWidth - sliderWidth - 70, 0, sliderWidth, 44)];
            [radiusSlider setMinimumValue:1];
            [radiusSlider setMaximumValue:50];
            [radiusSlider setValue:25];
            [radiusSlider setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
            [radiusSlider setTag:20]; // zur Erkennung, ob die View schon erstellt wurde
            [radiusSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(radiusSliderChangedValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:radiusSlider];
        }

    }
```

How can I stop this behavior ?

Thanks in advance
Chris

Comment: Once send the whole cell for row at index code.And one important point you should not allocate the out of the if condition  if (<cell> == nil)
        {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not being moved to another cell. This is because cells are **dequeued**.

This line...

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NewsTickerFilterCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

checks a cache of available cells and returns one (or creates a new one if there isn't one available). When cells move off the screen they are then reused. This means you can have a table with thousands of cells and not run out of memory.

Anyway, to fix it you need to work with this. You are already using `viewWithTag` so I'll stick to that but it would be better to have a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass to do this.

So...

```
// I will ignore the else for demonstration purposes because I don't know what came before it
if (indexPath.row == 2) {

    UISlider *radiusSlider = (UISlider *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:20];
    if (!radiusSlider) {
        // ... noch nicht erstellt
        radiusSlider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(screenWidth - sliderWidth - 70, 0, sliderWidth, 44)];
        [radiusSlider setMinimumValue:1];
        [radiusSlider setMaximumValue:50];
        [radiusSlider setValue:25];
        [radiusSlider setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [radiusSlider setTag:20]; // zur Erkennung, ob die View schon erstellt wurde
        [radiusSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(radiusSliderChangedValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:radiusSlider];
    }
} else {
    // remove the slider from the cell if not row 2
    UISlider *radiusSlider = (UISlider *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:20];
    [radiusSlider removeFromSuperView];
}
```

**Using a custom class**

You would have a couple of methods like this...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // register your custom cell class with this reuse identifier in view did load
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NewsTickerFilterCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // this is pretty much all that should happen in here.
    [self configureSliderCell:(MyCustomSliderCell *)cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

- (void)configureSliderCell:(MyCustomSliderCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //other configuration stuff here

    // the slider will already exist and be in the cell and be an outlet property
    // it will have the correct frame, min, max, etc...
    // all you need to do here is hide or show it depending on which row it is.
    cell.radiusSlider.hidden = indexPath.row != 2;
}
```

Comment: I think the best solution would be a custom cell for this approach. Everything else would be just a work around. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @ChristianPappenberger I've edited to show how you might do this with a custom cell subclass.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are adding the slider to cell, but IOS will reuse the same cell. So if you want to remove the slider do something like this:

```
if (indexPath.row == 2) {

    UISlider *radiusSlider = (UISlider *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:20];
    if (!radiusSlider) {

        // ... noch nicht erstellt
        radiusSlider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(screenWidth - sliderWidth - 70, 0, sliderWidth, 44)];
        [radiusSlider setMinimumValue:1];
        [radiusSlider setMaximumValue:50];
        [radiusSlider setValue:25];
        [radiusSlider setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [radiusSlider setTag:20]; // zur Erkennung, ob die View schon erstellt wurde
        [radiusSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(radiusSliderChangedValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:radiusSlider];
    }

}
else {
    UISlider *radiusSlider = (UISlider *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:20];
    [radiusSlider removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Just remove the slider from superview for other cells.

**EDIT**

As mentioned in Ramesh Muthe's comment below, this solution is not the best way to do this. This is just a work around. I would advice you to make a custom cell for your purpose.

Comment: This solution may resolve the issue but it is not the right one, because every time when you scroll the table the slider allocates again

Comment: Okay I understand. Thanks four your advice ! :)

Comment: @RameshMuthe I know. The best solution would be to use a custom cell. This is just a work around for his problem. Anyway has edited my answer so that it can be more helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because iOS reuse the cells. If you change the cell, change it's Identifier too.